# Laravel send email to address from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

In my index view I show all the users and there is a button that will change the user status to active and not active. The code looks like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->surname}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>
            @if($user->is_active == 0)
                {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PUT', 'action'=>['AdminUserController@activateuser', $user->id]]) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Activate', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            @else
                {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PUT', 'action'=>['AdminUserController@activateuser', $user->id]]) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('De-Activate', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            @endif
        </td>
        <td>{{$user->cell}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">View Property</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

So when I click on activate/deactivate button I trigger my activateuser function of the controller. After activation, an email is sent.
The controller looks like this:

```
public function activateuser(Request $request, $id){
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    if($user->is_active == 0){
        $user->update([$user->is_active = 1]);
        Mail::send(new activateUser());
    }
    else{
        $user->update([$user->is_active = 0]);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

At the moment the email is going to myself and my Mailabçe looks like this:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.activateuser')->to('wosleybago@gmail.com');
}
```

What I want instead is to send the email to the email address from the user email in the database table.

How can I do that?

So, someho I should get the $user->email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually want my emails have all the information in *itself*, so I pass `User` instance or whatever instance that holds data required to compose the mail.

So the `Mailable` has `__construct(..)` like this:

```
/**
 * @var \App\User
 */
public $user; // since this is a public property its going to be available in view of mailable as $user

__construct(App\User $user) {
    $this->user = $user;

    // further more I set the to(), this is what you are after
    $this->to($user->email, $user->name);

    // and subject
    $this->subject('You are activated!');
}

...
```

And now all you need to do in the controller is the following:

```
Mail::send(new activateUser($user));
```

As mentioned above, `$user` is available in the mail-view so you can use it there as well:

```
Hi, {{ $user->name }},
...
```

> **Note**: change the `activateUser` to `ActivateUser` to [follow PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md#1-overview)
>
> > Class names MUST be declared in **StudlyCaps**.

---

I also use queued mails so I set the `$timeout` and `$tries` properties right on the `Mailable` class.

Comment: I seem to understand this answer more because it is almost like what they use in the docummentation. I received the email with the subject, but I do not seem to see the name. Instead, above the subject I see "Example"

Comment: @deSousa I think your `$user->name` has `'Example'` set as `name` in the database, is that correct? :) You can just use `$this->to($user->email)` instead.

Comment: not at all. When I use the $user->name in my view I get the correct name. But the Email recipient(Hope it's the correct word) name says Example

Comment: @deSousa Hmm, you can try debug this using `dd()`, insert `dd($this);` in the end of constructor and see whats in the `+to` property. It should look like the following `+to: array:1 [0 => array:2 ["name" => "Mr. Joe Doe", "address" => "joe@doe.com"]]`

Comment: Just for clarification. Your code is right. If I check my email, on the "To" section, it gives me the email of the person am sending the email as well as the name. 
But on the "from" part I see: From: Example "my email address"
I set the sender via the .env file

Comment: Oh I see, thats because of your `config/mail.php` → `from` configuration.

Comment: Just went to the mail.php and changed the from to this:    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Admin'),
    ],
I still see Example. 
I used this command:php artisan cache:clear, but still see exampl

Comment: @deSousa Yea you need to read on the Laravel thing :), usually getters (like `config()`, `session()`, `env()`) use this signature `getter('value', 'default value')`, that means if `value` is not present in this case you would not have `MAIL_FROM_NAME` filled in the .env file it will take the `Admin` value instead, so you need to change OR delete the .env key-value pair, depends on what you want / need.

Comment: Fixed. Instead of cache:clear I just had to use config:cache artisan command instead.
Appreciate the patience on supporting

Answer (score 1):

Sending email is described in Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#sending-mail

Put this code inside activateUser() function

```
Mail::to($user)->send(new YourMailableName());
```

Do not forget to import Mail and YourMailableName using "use" keyword.

Or you can use user email instead object

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new YourMailableName());
```

And remove ->to('wosleybago@gmail.com') from your Mailable/

Comment: I tried this and it works. How can I configure the subject of the email?
I tried this but it gives an error: Mail::to($user->email)->subject('Account Activation')->send(new activateUser());

Comment: Use subject function inside your mailable in build function. return $this->view('emails.activateuser')->subject('Subject');

Answer (score 1):

You should pass User Email in when creating new activateUser instance, like so

```
 Mail::send(new activateUser($user->email));
```

And then use this attribute later.

Answer (score 1):

Sending Email to particular a person is quite simple. My suggestion would be as follows:

- Use Queue to send mail later as it will take some time to respond from controller to view.
- In existing code you can get the email of the current user and send it using a helper to() that comes with mail functionality of laravel.
  You can code it like this.

  ```
  if($user->is_active == 0){
      $user->update([$user->is_active = 1]);
      Mail::to($user->email)->send(new MailableClassInstance);
  }
  ```

Comment: I also figured that will need to use the queue. Following @Kyslik, how can I use queue. I tried to add inside the controller and it does not really work: Mail::queue(send(new ActivateUser($user)));
Also tried to add in the construtor of the mailable but does not work either.

Comment: Please follow this link to know more about how to work with queues to send email at the back end. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#creating-jobs You will find all the related details.